# How I access HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject() in javascript(.js) file which is used in my application?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am using javascript file for validtion. Now I have to localize that javascript file. I want to HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject() in .js file. Can I use HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject() in my .js file? Is there any other option to locaize javascript file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

Resource is the name of Resource file and Greetings is Resource key

```
   <script type = "text/javascript">  
            function ShowGreetings() {  
                var message = '<%=GetGlobalResourceObject("Resource", "Greetings") %>';  
                alert(message);  
            }  
        </script>
```

also read this : http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/698097.aspx