# use GetGlobalResourceObject function in external javascript file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, globalization

I want to access global resources in external java script file in ASP.NET using GetGlobalResourceObject() function. Please help to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer to a similar question on SO 
[How I access HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject() in javascript(.js) file which is used in my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763013/how-i-access-httpcontext-getglobalresourceobject-in-javascript-js-file-which) I hope this helps you out.